# Twitter json feed?

Tags: json, twitter, jsonp, feed

Does anyone know where I can find a json feed for this page?

```
http://twitter.com/#!/microsoft
```

The closest I have found is this:

```
http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/microsoft.json
```

but that does not include all the tweets, i.e.

> " ... that server room is going to be
>   empty soon & we’re going to install my
>   Jacuzzi in it." http://bit.ly/j1N82d

is missing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems the method you're using to request the feed has been deprecated (at least I couldn't find it in the [current docs](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline)). Anyways here's what I would do:

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=microsoft&include_rts=1
```

This will fetch 20 of microsoft's latest tweets, and `include_rts=1` will include any retweets by them.

Comment: I'm getting a 403 forbidden message in the http response header when I point my browser to that url.

Comment: NOTE (Jun 11-2013) : The above link used API v1. Which is deprecated and cannot be used anymore!